# Storing list of android apps

Tags: java, android

Is the android app **package name** unique across all apps on the device as well as the Market?

I want to store all app related information in a data structure. Right now, I am planning to use **HashMap** for this purpose.

```
HashMap<string,AppInfo> appList; //string (key), value is AppInfo object
```

Here I am planning to use the *app package name (E.g. com.a.b.c)* as the **key** since I believe it is unique to the android app. Appinfo **(value)** is a custom object that contains the app-related information I need.

Is this the best choice for data structure (in terms of ease of access and easy addition and deletion) and key property? Any suggestions that are better design-wise and/or performance-wise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the android app package name unique across all apps on the device as well as the Market?

It is unique across all apps on the device. For any given app, it is unique on the Play Store. However:

- that may not be true of other distribution channels, though ideally it would be
- a given app may have multiple distinct versions on the distribution channel (alpha vs. release, APK splits for NDK binaries), each of which would have the same package name (a.k.a., application ID)

> Is this the best choice for data structure (in terms of ease of access and easy addition and deletion) and key property?

That's impossible to answer in the abstract.

> Any suggestions that are better design-wise and/or performance-wise?

If your number of apps is small, you might consider an `ArrayMap` or `SimpleArrayMap` for better memory consumption.

If your number of apps is huge, plan to store them in a database, and look them up from there.

Comment: But would it be possible to have an alpha and release version of the same app on the device at the same time?  I think that's what he's asking.

Comment: @commonsware : Is there a better choice for a key than the app package name? Or is this the best way to uniquely identify apps on the device?

Comment: Please let me know if I need to expand on my question in any way?

Comment: @DeeV: On the device, there can only be one. I mention the distribution channel points due to the "as well as the Market?" portion of the question. On the device, there can only be one; in a distribution channel, there is only one "logical" app per package name, but there might be distinct editions of that app.

Comment: @SoulRayder: "Is there a better choice for a key than the app package name?" -- I have no idea. You are the only one who knows what you are trying to do here. *Probably* it is a reasonable choice. "Or is this the best way to uniquely identify apps on the device?" -- on the device, it should be fine.

Comment: @CommonsWare : Thanks, thats what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The package name is how the Play Store identifies apps. The device will also not install an app of the same package name without the same signature. If it has the same signature, then the new app is installed over. So a person couldn't side-load an app with the same package name.